# Undefined global variables in function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to perform calculations on a button click because I don't want the page to refresh when this button is clicked. I wrote a script below:

```
var name = document.getElementById('recipeName').value;
var lvl = document.getElementById('recipeLvl').value;
var e = document.getElementById("qualitySelect");
var quality = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
e = document.getElementById("classSelect");
var craft = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var mat1 = document.getElementById('material1Name').value;
var mat1Qty = document.getElementById('material1Qty').value;
var mat1NQ = document.getElementById('material1NQ').value;
var mat1NQprice = document.getElementById('material1NQprice').value;
var mat1HQ = document.getElementById('material1HQ').value;
var mat1HQprice = document.getElementById('material1HQprice').value;
var mat2 = document.getElementById('material2Name').value;
var mat2Qty = document.getElementById('material2Qty').value;
var mat2NQ = document.getElementById('material2NQ').value;
var mat2NQprice = document.getElementById('material2NQprice').value;
var mat2HQ = document.getElementById('material2HQ').value;
var mat2HQprice = document.getElementById('material2HQprice').value;
var mat3 = document.getElementById('material3Name').value;
var mat3Qty = document.getElementById('material3Qty').value;
var mat3NQ = document.getElementById('material3NQ').value;
var mat3NQprice = document.getElementById('material3NQprice').value;
var mat3HQ = document.getElementById('material3HQ').value;
var mat3HQprice = document.getElementById('material3HQprice').value;
var mat4 = document.getElementById('material4Name').value;
var mat4Qty = document.getElementById('material4Qty').value;
var mat4NQ = document.getElementById('material4NQ').value;
var mat4NQprice = document.getElementById('material4NQprice').value;
var mat4HQ = document.getElementById('material4HQ').value;
var mat4HQprice = document.getElementById('material4HQprice').value;
var mat5 = document.getElementById('material5Name').value;
var mat5Qty = document.getElementById('material5Qty').value;
var mat5NQ = document.getElementById('material5NQ').value;
var mat5NQprice = document.getElementById('material5NQprice').value;
var mat5HQ = document.getElementById('material5HQ').value;
var mat5HQprice = document.getElementById('material5HQprice').value;
var mat6 = document.getElementById('material6Name').value;
var mat6Qty = document.getElementById('material6Qty').value;
var mat6NQ = document.getElementById('material6NQ').value;
var mat6NQprice = document.getElementById('material6NQprice').value;
var mat6HQ = document.getElementById('material6HQ').value;
var mat6HQprice = document.getElementById('material6HQprice').value;
e = document.getElementById("catalyst1");
var crystal1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
e = document.getElementById('element1');
var element1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var crystal1Qty = document.getElementById('crystalQty1').value;
var crystal1Price = document.getElementById('crystalPrice1').value;
e = document.getElementById("catalyst2");
var crystal2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
e = document.getElementById('element2');
var element2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var crystal2Qty = document.getElementById('crystalQty2').value;
var crystal2Price = document.getElementById('crystalPrice2').value;
var notes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
var marketPrice = document.getElementById('marketPrice').value;

function calculate() {
  var mat1Cost = (mat1NQ * mat1NQprice) + (mat1HQ * mat1HQprice);
  var mat2Cost = (mat2NQ * mat2NQprice) + (mat2HQ * mat2HQprice);
  var mat3Cost = (mat3NQ * mat3NQprice) + (mat3HQ * mat3HQprice);
  var mat4Cost = (mat4NQ * mat4NQprice) + (mat4HQ * mat4HQprice);
  var mat5Cost = (mat5NQ * mat5NQprice) + (mat5HQ * mat5HQprice);
  var mat6Cost = (mat6NQ * mat6NQprice) + (mat6HQ * mat6HQprice);
  var crystal1Cost = (crystal1Qty * crystal1Price);
  var crystal2Cost = (crystal2Qty * crystal2Price);
  var total = mat1Cost +
    mat1Cost +
    mat1Cost +
    mat1Cost +
    mat1Cost +
    mat1Cost +
    crystal1Cost +
    crystal2Cost;
  document.getElementById('totalCost').value = mat1Cost;
  return false;
}
```

I'm new to javascript, and thought declaring the variables right after  would make them accessible to any function that I would need to use them in, but they are undefined in the calculate function. If I declare them in calculate() it's fine, so is this a scope problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide your html also

Comment: When/where are you calling the function?

Comment: Do you realize that the values are recorded when the script runs, not when the function is called. The value does not get auto updated in the variables when the input's value changes.

Comment: Where are you putting this code, and where is `calculate()`? If you don't wait for the page to load before using `getElementById`, it won't find any of the elements.

Comment: I'm calling the function with an onclick in a button: <td class="button"><input type="image" class="button" src="res/img/Calculate.png" alt="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="return calculate()"></td>

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code example could be a bit more minimal: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're grabbing the elements values before you've assigned anything to them. You're getting a *copy*, not a *reference.*

```js
var initialValue = document.getElementById('text').value;

function clickHandler() {
  // Notice how I have to grab the value again when I want an updated value
  var updatedValue = document.getElementById('text').value;
  console.log('Initial:', initialValue);
  console.log('Updated:', updatedValue);
}
```

```html
<input id="text" />
<button onclick="clickHandler()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: So what is happening is that my function is running but the script isn't assigning values to the variables outside the function?

Comment: @Rwarfield The problem is that those elements *don't have any values* when you first load the page. You need to fill them in then grab the values later. It's like if you ask me for a burger and I say "I don't have one right now." If you ask me for a burger *later* I might have one to give you but you have to ask me for it again. I'm not going to come tell you that I have a burger automatically.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now, it's assigning values to those when the page is first loaded and all the inputs are blank, or the script runs on page load. So on the button click I have to declare the variables to get the values again. I have to declare them in the function, is there a way to run the entire script again? I was trying to not have to declare the variables in every function that I needed them in, but rather just once.

Comment: @Rwarfield You don't have to redeclare them but you do have to re-assign them. You could write a function which re-assigns them and call that.

Answer (score 1):

@epascarello has commented the real answer, there is no much science there, this is javascript, therefore is a script language, so as soon as this file is loaded, those variables are filled with the initial data of each field, so, if you want to get the value at the point you press calculate(), you should get your variables.